# thymeleaf submit button code

Tags: java, maven, thymeleaf

Can anyone explain how is **thymeleaf**'s submit button working in the following code?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>   
 <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"           

  layout:decorator="master">
<head>
    <title>LoginPage</title>
</head>

<body>
 <h1>Login Page</h1>
<!-- Any content you put in the div fragment below will appear on the page-->
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">

    <P th:if="${loginError}" >Wrong User or Password</P>

        <form th:action="@{/new}" th:Object="${messageForm}"        
                    method="post">
        <label for ="User">User Name</label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{user}"/><br/>
        <label for ="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password"  th:field="*{password}"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </form>

        </div>
</div>
</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I switched tag scala with java. There's nothing on thymeleaf suggesting scala's being a prerequisite. It looks like a standard java framework to me.

Comment: Can you please provide some more context? I guess there must be one or more java classes underlying this template, from which to evaluate the custom template expressions (like `${messageForm}` or `@{/new}`). Could you point out a tutorial or doc from which this template was taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<form>` template gets rendered as a standard form with a `POST` call made when you submit.
What's  added by the framework is that form fields are dynamically bound to an underlying object, referenced by the `th:Object="${messageForm}"` attribute.

Each field is computed calling a method on the `messageForm` object with the `th:field="*{password}"` syntax.

Finally, the `POST` call is made to the URL created by evaluating the `th:action="@{/new}"` attribute, probably relative to the current page.

Comment: YEah this is i really want

Answer (score 1):

Everything that follows can be found in this [Getting Started](http://www.thymeleaf.org/standarddialect5minutes.html) page.

From a first look I'd say that the `<form>` template gets rendered as a standard form with a `POST` call made when you submit.

It's not much more than plain http/html. What's added by the framework is that form fields are dynamically bound to an underlying object, referenced by the `th:Object="${messageForm}"` attribute.

Each field is computed calling a method on the `messageForm` object with the `th:field="*{password}"` syntax.

Finally, the POST call is made to the URL created by evaluating the `th:action="@{/new}"` attribute, probably relative to the current page.

---

Let's make an example to clarify.
Suppose we have

- an object `messageForm` of type `MessageForm` with attributes
- `user` of type `String`
- `password` of type `String`
- the template is being rendered as a web page with url `"http://my.app.com/login"`

What you probably get by submitting the button, is that the `messageForm` object will have its attributes `user` and `password` set to the values you put in the form's corresponding fields, and than the form will call a `"http://my.app.com/new"` page, or similar, passing the `messageForm` object from which to check the credentials for login operation...

---

If you didn't already, I strongly recommend you to read the [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html) on thymeleaf website before going on.